# Will a neural network, having randomized weights, give the same prediction rate every time?

Tags: matlab, neural-network

For a input, having randomized weights, will my efficiency of prediction change?
Also I haven't considered biases in my network, is it the possible reason of less efficiency( I am getting prediction rate of 93% for training data of 200 examples and 90% for testing data consisting of 100 examples. I have taken learning rate as 0.01 and error threshold 0.005. I have employed the backpropagation algorithm)

Comment: This is really hard to understand what you are asking about, title asks about reproduciblity, question itself does not - what is the actual question here?

Comment: So by randomized weights: do you mean random initial weight assignment, which is usually done in the neural networks (weights are taken from a specific random distribution). Also, is 90% testing accuracy bad? We cannot tell. Maybe 93% training accuracy is bad if your data is not too difficult.

Comment: If I consider your question title as the entire question (anyway the body of the question doesn't make sense(, then the answer is no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned before: A network with randomized weights is an untrained network. It's, if it's having a good accuracy with random weights, just by accident.

If you think of a neutral net and especially of Backpropagation as an optimization process for the function

f(x) = mx + b

where the goal is to find the best matching line for all training sets.

The initial step is to choose a random value for m and b. The probability that the line is close to optimal match by a wild guess, which is the random initialize, is very small.

The goal of Backpropagation is to determine the optimal settings for m and b by propagating the error of the current setting back into the network and to adjust those until a acceptable setting is found. The adjustment is done by gradient descent which is used to find a minima of the error surface which is created by the difference between the output and the target value of all training samples.

If this is not what you meant by your question and you ask for the influence of the initial randomized weights on the training outcome:

It's depending on the function that you want to optimize. If the error surface is non-convex, as it is in most cases, then the initial values define the starting point of the gradient descent and will hence influence the training outcome.

Think of the error surface as a mountain landscape with several valleys. The goal of the gradient descent is to reach one of these valleys and in the best case scenario the deepest one, the global minima. Since the gradient descent usually tends to get stuck in first found minima (depending on learning rate and momentum), the answer is no. The found minima depends on the starting location. So, you will usually get different accuracy with different initial weights.

I recently did some experiments with the randomization of weights. My result was that if the variance of the random generated numbers is too big, the network never converges to a proper solution.

Comment: So when I am randomly initializing the weights in the beginning and using the trained weights for testing, I get accuracy of prediction sometimes 96% and sometimes 98%. So what should I do to ensure that the global minima is achieved during gradient descent.should i fix my initial weights?

Comment: That's correct. The answer to your question is simply: you can't ensure the global minima. What you can do is to try different random number generators like Gaussian distributed generators. You can also parallel  train a couple of networks with different initial weights to determine the best settings. There are also certain optimizations like momentum and weight decay to improve the learning process. Since you didn't provided your network topology it's hard to give suggestions. The learning rate is also a factor to consider when it comes to leaning improvements.

Comment: I have a function y=(x1)^2 + 2*(x2 )+(x3 )+ 3*(x4)^3 of which I have to predict the value. So I have 4 inputs in input layer, 1 hidden layer and 2 nodes in output layer s.t output is [1 0] if y is positive and output is [0 1] if y is negative.inputs are between 0 and 1, weights between -1 and 1. Alpha is 0.01 and threshold is 0.005. When I train my data for 200 examples , I get 94% on training data and 86% on test data(for 4 nodes in hidden layer).

Comment: And I get 90.2% accuracy on a training set of 250 examples and 96%  on test data. And also running the same program again yields different accuracy on training and test data(due to randomised weights). So now can u suggest how exactly can I increase my accuracy to achieve 98% - 100%.

Comment: To avoid large comment conversations and to improve the chances that other people can benefit from your problem: Ask your current question as a new question and check this one as answered if my answer is the correct one for your initial question. You can afterwards benefit from other users answers as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Neural Network, then your efficiency (I'd rather call it accuracy) of prediction should generally decrease.

I'd explain it in this fashion.

A neural network trains its weights and biases to obtain the desired output for a given set of inputs (training data). The neural network uses the backpropagation algorithm to obtain a set of weights that is "most" optimal for the network given a certain number of iterations (epochs).

When you are testing the prediction accuracy of your network on a test dataset, you'd prefer the trained weights and biases (obtained from training the neural network on training dataset) as they have been trained to generate the desired results (output). If you test the prediction accuracy of your network on random weights and biases, your prediction accuracy is generally lower and may vary in a large range.

You may be surprised that your prediction accuracy on a test dataset with randomized weights is higher than those predicted by the weights and biases trained on a training dataset. Albeit it is rare, it may happen and in that case the randomized weights are close to your optimal weights for the network.

Summarily, it is always better to test your network on trained weights and biases and not on randomized weights. Otherwise, what is the purpose of machine learning algorithms.

Comment: I am pretty sure this is not what OP is asking about, take a look at question title. Nothing in his question suggests that he wants to randomize the weights after training and before testing.

Comment: @lejlot. His question seems a little weird. The title and the body of the question are different. Should I remove my answer